# I need help in changing the src of a file in a function written in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I want the src of the ga.js to read from my js/ folder and not from google-analytics. I have the ga.js file on my server and want to map the link to that and not from google-analytics.com. I don't know JavaScript. so any help would be much appreciated.
Below is the function. The line i need editing is the third line.

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the function line the one below i don't know why do you want to do this but modify your code like the one below,replace localpath with your path where the file is stored

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = '\localpath\ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Comment: This is exactly what i thought. but being that it was javascript, i was not too sure if i would be doing something wrong by changing it this way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

`ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';`

to:
`ga.src = 'js/dummy.js';`

Comment: This is exactly what i thought. but being that it was javascript, i was not too sure if i would be doing something wrong by changing it this way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know what else your code is doing, but I must point out that this could cause code errors if your app is expecting Google tracking functions to be available.

Answer (score 0):

Change your src attribute to point directly to your "ga.js" file into the /js/ folder:

```
ga.src = '/js/ga.js';
```

You can find more information about the source attribute here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp